# Really-High-Speed Train for Kids

Tags: trains

In a country where a majority of the population is children (like, for example, Niger), and where the terrain is often mountainous, engineers build a very-high speed train (say, 500-1000 km/hr), with a very low ceiling (say, 3-4 feet high)and perhaps also a very narrow body. The train is mainly intended to be used by young children, though older kids and small adults who don't mind squishing or lying down the whole trip can also use it. The idea here is that, because air resistance increases exponentially in relation to speed [I'm assuming that a vacuum tube train is not viable..but that maglev trains could be, to reduce surface friction..], and because many underpasses and mountain tunnels would also need to be built for it, the train should be as small and aerodynamically shaped as possible. At times, this low-ceilinged rail line would also be usable for low-speed cargo-only trains. My question is, how much more aerodynamic could a train like this be in comparison to conventionally-sized potentially very high speed trains? And between the aerodynamic gain and the smaller tunnels, how much $ could be saved overall, in theory?

Comment: You shoot your kids to school.. Bye daddy see you at lunch ! TsjPffffff.. it would be a good idea for parents in urban regions, where people use cars to bring their children to school and cause traffic jams. But before you can calculate the yield, you'd have to make an estimate of the investment ! This thing better be *very* safe..

Comment: Haha, yes it would need to be. At the risk of getting too dark here, it might become a target for violent crazies wanting to carry out a horrible attack...

If you had an urban version, in a kid-filled, traffic-filled city (Lagos?), the way to try to make it safe would probably be: a) make it a normal speed subway, not high speed; and b) put it directly, immediately under a street-level pedestrian path, with the ability for the whole line to open up to let the kids escape in case of a fire, etc 

But even then, doing a cost-benefit financial analysis of this sort of thing is way beyond me

Comment: *"Air resistance increases exponentially in relation to speed":* it doesn't. It is proportional to the square of the speed.

Comment: Doesn't that imply an exponential relationship?

Comment: No it doesn't. Duh. Quantity $a$ increases exponentially with respect to quantity $b$ if $a \propto e^{kb}$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: P.S. The thing with Niger is that the vast majority (80%) of the population lives in rural areas. High speed trains do not serve rural areas, for the obvious reasons.

Comment: "*In a* [stable, wealthy] *country where a majority of the population is children*" why are throngs of small, unaccompanied children traveling?

Answer (score 6):

Drag can be expressed as $D=1/2 \rho v^nC_xA$, where $\rho$ is the density of the medium, $n$ is an exponent dependent on the velocity range, $C_x$ is the drag coefficient and $A$ is the area of the cross sectional area of the surface exposed to the flow.

As you can see, if you reduce the cross section by a factor $S$, all the rest being the same, you are also reducing the drag by the same factor.

Similar consideration for the economics: assuming your costs for drilling a tunnel are linear with the cross section of the tunnel, the reduction is the same.

By the way, also normal adults can ride in your small train: they just need to lay on their back or sit like F1 drivers.

Comment: Great point. Maybe F1 can sponsor it! And adult tickets would need to be at least double the price.. 

So, my math is pretty bad, I understand what you're saying but it's hard for me to translate it into 'practicalities'. If this F1 train had a cross-section that is only a 1/3 as big as a conventional really-high speed train (and help me out here..is that 1/3 assumption likely to be near the mark?), and if the two trains were both going, say, 800 km/hr, how much fuel savings might the F1 train experience?

Comment: @JshupacFuture-Economics: You would use one third of the fuel of the normal sized train. (Which sounds great until you realize that fuel costs are not all that important for trains; costs with personnel and the infrastructure are vastly more important than costs with fuel. Trains are not airliners; for airliners, yes, costs with fuel dominate.)

Comment: Fuel costs on trains are unimportant even at extreme high speeds? And what if personnel costs are very low because of automation?

Comment: All aboard the coffin train!

Comment: @JshupacFuture-Economics: With high speed rail the bulk of the cost is the infrastructure. High speed railways are fantastically expensive to build; and expensive to maintain, but that's small compared to the cost of building them in the first place. It's usually something like 20 million euros or dollars per km of track; the Chinese are supposed to be able to build a high speed line with 17 million dollars per km, and that is considered a great achievement in cost reduction. The cost needs to be amortized over a reasonable time, say 25 years; coming to about 500,000 dollars per km per year.

Comment: Doesn't a lot of that cost come from large tunnels and low underpasses/high overpasses and viaducts though?

Comment: Also, don't most Chinese trains top out at like 300-400 km/h only?

Comment: @JshupacFuture-Economics: Yes they do. The infrastructure for a railway capable of supporting train speeds of over 500 km/h will of course be much more expensive. (And I am not sure why you would think that a viaduct supporting a metre gauge track would be so much cheaper than a viaduct supporting a standard gauge track.)

Comment: @AlexP I was thinking you could avoid the need to build viaducts in many cases by going with underpasses or tunnels instead?

Comment: Data points: In North America, Texas HSR is budgeted at about \$90 million per km across the plains of Texas. California HSR is slightly better, at about \$80 million per km across the Central Valley.

Answer (score 1):

## The costs will *rise*

Let me preface this. There are many factors at play here. Your solution can be cheaper in construction and day by day expenses. However, in rekative terms you might have to shell out more money.

First of all there are benefits to increasing size. If the train will get proportionally bigger, you'll have more m³ for the surface area. That means a normal train has more friction overall, but per m³ you have less friction than the child train. To solve this I would make it a double dekker train. Of course this only works from a certain length train, as the drag at the front is much bigger than on the sides.

The other costs is in development. Ironically you'll need a lot of extra research and most likely specialised equipment to make all the train and rails. If you use most of the already implemented standards around the world you can use existing knowledge, expertise and equipment. This futher reduces the costs in comparison to the child train. Not to mention the standard way we move goods around the world. Moving it on the child train line would require transferring the goods to different containers. It is a logistical nightmare you shouldn't touch.

So my advice is this. Use current standards, expertise and equipment to build the child train line. Only adapt the train to child double dekker. This will allow for a lot of money saved compared to the proposed child train.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an enthusiastic rider and supporter of high speed rail. 300+ kph in seats more comfortable than on an economy airline flight is a great way to travel.

Yes, a kid sized train would be cheaper, put price isn't just about diameters (of train cars and tunnels). You still need rails, power cables, train stations, control stations, etc.

Don't forget that there are some middle schoolers who have already reached adult height. Yes, even a regular adukt can crawl in, but passenger capacity per car will be small.

A full sized HSR (5 seats per row in economy class in the trains I ride) could have dedicated runs for children at the beginning and end of the school day while carrying adults at other times. Overnight, the same train could be used to carry express packages if noone wants to ride in the middle of the night - and no one would need to crawl on hands and knees to load and unload it.

What you propose is technically feasable (as soon as next generation HSR glides out slightly above its rails), but I think you'll need a unique environment to make it more desirable than full sized HSR cars.

Answer (score 0):

Let me turn this around.

Both a child and an adult will occupy much the same cross area if they are lying down and coming feet first. So why not make an even slimmer train that everyone can ride in the same position as they would a waterslide?

You can now transport anyone with the same low costs and standards. And when things get derailed (as they will in a country that has too many children for too few adults), each cart can double as a collective coffin so you just have to cover them with earth.